# FM to Download ABAP report output to PC as text

Tags: abap, function-module

Is there any function module aside from `GUI_DOWNLOAD` to download the ABAP report output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "ABAP report output", I am guessing you mean the list output.

You can use function module `DOWNLOAD_LIST` from within an ABAP report program to download the list, or any of the current lists in the stack.

Alternatively, use function module `LIST_TO_ASCI` to get the list into an internal table, then download it with `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_DOWNLOAD` (`GUI_DOWNLOAD` will work, but it is recommended you use CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES instead). (Look at function group `SLST` for some other interesting list processing functions).

If you didn't mean the list output, then in general use `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_DOWNLOAD` for downloading internal tables.

That is of course, if you are looking to download to the client PC. If you want to create a file on the application server, look at the keyword help for `OPEN DATASET` and related commands.